# Hello, what to do when UV Image Editor is completely gray?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

[image]

In edit Mode, everything is selected. 
I was rotating a UV map of one of the wall faces so it would look better in Unity, but then it became completely gray. Restart didn't help.

HAALP!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably hiden the *UV Editor* grid accidentally. To restore it hold the <kbd>Mouse Scroll</kbd> and drag the mouse left/right/up/down. You may also scroll the mouse wheel to make it appear. Another method is pressing the <kbd>Home</kbd> button.
[image]

Comment: Ah true, thanks for that. Home button helped. It was so small and hidden than even searching with scroll button didn't help.